# How to Configure CloudWatch Lambda Insights in Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, amazon-cloudwatch

I need to enable "CloudWatch Lambda Insights" for a lambda using Terraform, but could not find the documentation. How I can do it in Terraform?

Note: This question [How to add CloudWatch Lambda Insights to serverless config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65217527/how-to-add-cloudwatch-lambda-insights-to-serverless-config) may be relevant.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is no "boolean switch" in the `aws_lambda_function` resource of the AWS Terraform provider that you can set to `true`, that would enable Cloudwatch Lambda Insights.

Fortunately, it is possible to do this yourself. The following Terraform definitions are based on this AWS documentation: [Using the AWS CLI to enable Lambda Insights on an existing Lambda function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Lambda-Insights-Getting-Started-cli.html)

The process involves two steps:

1. Add a *layer* to your Lambda
2. Attach a AWS *policy* to your Lambdas role.

The Terraform definitions would look like this:

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "insights_example" {
  [...]

  layers = [
    "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:580247275435:layer:LambdaInsightsExtension:14"
  ]
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "insights_policy" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.insights_example.id
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/CloudWatchLambdaInsightsExecutionRolePolicy"
}
```

**Important**: The `arn` of the layer is different for each region. The documentation I linked above has a [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Lambda-Insights-extension-versions.html) to a list of them. Furthermore, there is an additional step required if your Lambda is in a VPC, which you can read about in the documentation. The described "VPC step" can be put into Terraform as well.

---

**For future readers:** The version of that layer in my example is `14`. This will change over time. So please do not just copy & paste that part. Follow the provided links and look for the current version of that layer.

---

### Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example

Tested with:

```
Terraform v0.14.4
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/archive v2.0.0
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws v3.24.0
```

Create the following two files (`handler.py` and `main.tf`) in a folder. Then run the following commands:

1. `terraform init`
2. `terraform plan`
3. `terraform apply`

Besides deploying the required resources, it will also create a zip archive containing the `handler.py` which is the deployment artifact used by the `aws_lambda_function` resource. So this is an all-in-one example without the need of further zipping etc.

**handler.py**

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    return { 
        'message' : 'CloudWatch Lambda Insights Example'
    }
```

**main.tf**

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 3.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-1"
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "insights_example" {
  function_name = "insights-example"
  runtime       = "python3.8"
  handler       = "handler.lambda_handler"
  role          = aws_iam_role.insights_example.arn
  filename      = "${path.module}/lambda.zip"

  layers = [
    "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:580247275435:layer:LambdaInsightsExtension:14"
  ]

  depends_on = [
    data.archive_file.insights_example
  ]
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "insights_example" {
  name               = "InsightsExampleLambdaRole"
  assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.lambda_assume.json
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "insights_example" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.insights_example.id
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole"
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "insights_policy" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.insights_example.id
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/CloudWatchLambdaInsightsExecutionRolePolicy"
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "lambda_assume" {
  statement {
    effect  = "Allow"
    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]

    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["lambda.amazonaws.com"]
    }
  }
}

data "archive_file" "insights_example" {
  type        = "zip"
  source_file = "${path.module}/handler.py"
  output_path = "${path.module}/lambda.zip"
}
```

Comment: You could replace the hard-coding of the ARN of the layer with the [`aws_lambda_layer_version` data source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/lambda_layer_version).

Comment: @ydaetskcoR I checked the documentation and I don't know if that is possible. Although, the documentation is very thin. But the version data source does not allow to specify a `arn` to use etc. It only appears to make sense with the `resource` with the same name. But that requires _you_ to provide the layer. So as far as I can tell, you can not create a `aws_lambda_layer_version` data source from an existing arn. Can you provide an example?

Comment: I haven't actually used it but I expect you'd call it with `layer_name = LambdaInsightsExtension` and then potentially also set `compatible_runtime = "python3.8"` to match the runtime of the Lambda function. If you didn't set `compatible_runtime` then eventually you might end up with the latest `LambdaInsightsExtension` layer no longer supporting the `python3.8` runtime at some point in the future. I'd probably extract that to a local or a variable though and use it in both places.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR If you just set `LambdaInsightsExtension` as `layer_name`, where is the information about region and account id coming from? I tried a few things with my example above, but did not get it to work. I was never able to point to that specific `arn`.

Comment: Ah yeah I just tried using the AWS CLI to list it but it doesn't return anything even though you can see it with `aws lambda get-layer-version-by-arn --arn arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:580247275435:layer:LambdaInsightsExtension:14 --region us-east-2`. Unfortunately it doesn't look like the API accepts any way of taking the account ID either so there's not a current way to do this. Looks like I was wrong there, sorry :/

Answer (score 2):

In case you are using [container images](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-images.html) as the [deployment package](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/lambda_function#package_type) for your Lambda function, the required steps to enable CloudWatch Lambda Insights are slightly different (since Lambda layers can't be used here):

1. attach the `arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/CloudWatchLambdaInsightsExecutionRolePolicy` to your functions role as described by Jens
2. Add the Lambda Insights extension to your container image

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/nodejs:12

RUN curl -O https://lambda-insights-extension.s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/amazon_linux/lambda-insights-extension.rpm && \
    rpm -U lambda-insights-extension.rpm && \
    rm -f lambda-insights-extension.rpm

COPY app.js /var/task/
```

see [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Lambda-Insights-Getting-Started-docker.html) for details

Answer (score 2):

Based off [@jens' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65738550/1123556), here's a snippet that will automatically supply the correct `LambdaInsightsExtension` layer based on the current region:

```
data "aws_region" "current" {}

locals {
  aws_region = data.aws_region.current.name
  # List taken from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Lambda-Insights-extension-versionsx86-64.html
  lambdaInsightsLayers = {
    "us-east-1" : "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:580247275435:layer:LambdaInsightsExtension:18",
    "us-east-2" : "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:580247275435:layer:LambdaInsightsExtension:18",
    "us-west-1" : "arn:aws:lambda:us-west-1:580247275435:layer:LambdaInsightsExtension:18",
    "us-west-2" : "arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:580247275435:layer:LambdaInsightsExtension:18",
    "af-south-1" : "arn:aws:lambda:af-south-1:012438385374:layer:LambdaInsightsExtension:11",
    "ap-east-1" : "arn:aws:lambda:ap-east-1:519774774795:layer:LambdaInsightsExtension:11",
    "ap-south-1" : "arn:aws:lambda:ap-south-1:580247275435:layer:LambdaInsightsExtension:18",
    "ap-northeast-3" : "arn:aws:lambda:ap-northeast-3:194566237122:layer:LambdaInsightsExtension:1",
    "ap-northeast-2" : "arn:aws:lambda:ap-northeast-2:580247275435:layer:LambdaInsightsExtension:18",
    "ap-southeast-1" : "arn:aws:lambda:ap-southeast-1:580247275435:layer:LambdaInsightsExtension:18",
    "ap-southeast-2" : "arn:aws:lambda:ap-southeast-2:580247275435:layer:LambdaInsightsExtension:18",
    "ap-northeast-1" : "arn:aws:lambda:ap-northeast-1:580247275435:layer:LambdaInsightsExtension:25",
    "ca-central-1" : "arn:aws:lambda:ca-central-1:580247275435:layer:LambdaInsightsExtension:18",
    "eu-central-1" : "arn:aws:lambda:eu-central-1:580247275435:layer:LambdaInsightsExtension:18",
    "eu-west-1" : "arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:580247275435:layer:LambdaInsightsExtension:18",
    "eu-west-2" : "arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-2:580247275435:layer:LambdaInsightsExtension:18",
    "eu-south-1" : "arn:aws:lambda:eu-south-1:339249233099:layer:LambdaInsightsExtension:11",
    "eu-west-3" : "arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-3:580247275435:layer:LambdaInsightsExtension:18",
    "eu-north-1" : "arn:aws:lambda:eu-north-1:580247275435:layer:LambdaInsightsExtension:18",
    "me-south-1" : "arn:aws:lambda:me-south-1:285320876703:layer:LambdaInsightsExtension:11",
    "sa-east-1" : "arn:aws:lambda:sa-east-1:580247275435:layer:LambdaInsightsExtension:18"
  }
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "my_lambda" {
  ...

  layers = [
    local.lambdaInsightsLayers[local.aws_region]
  ]
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "insights_policy" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.my_lambda.id
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/CloudWatchLambdaInsightsExecutionRolePolicy"
}
```